# Way to make sure our functions use abbreviated types intead of primitives in F# other than to have to always write it ourselves?

Tags: .net, f#, functional-programming

Let's say I have defined some type abbreviation

```
type Individual = Double array
```

and that I am using it throughout my F# project:

```
let generateIndividual = [|1.0; 2.0|]
```

IntelliSense tells me `generateIndividual` has an associated return type of `float[]`. As I would prefer it to show up `Individual` as return type, I change its signature to

```
let generateIndividual : Individual = [|1.0; 2.0|]
```

When using internal code it really doesn't matter that much what Intellisense shows up. But when doing APIs to be used for the external world it seems prettier to have my functions show up the aliases rather than the primitive types.

Is there by chance any way to avoid having to type them up other than by the method shown above? By Swensen's suggestion I took a look at Signature files, and while at first they appeared to be just what I was looking for, they seem incapable of doing it.

Comment: You have essentially created two aliases to the same type. How do you expect the F# compiler to know which of those to infer?

Comment: I guess it cannot. But there might be some alternative (as it trying to use type abbreviations whether it could, for instance).

Answer (score 5):

Type aliases like your `Individual` are only visible in F# if you use explicit annotations to mark values (or function arguments and results) with the type. At compile-time, aliases are replaced with the actual type (e.g. `Double array`). This means that F# treats both as the same type and there is no way to guarantee that you'll only see the aliased name. You can add type annotations everywhere, but if someone else uses the type, they'll also have to do that.

If you want to make sure, you need to use a wrapper. A discriminated union with a single case is quite nice way to do this, because they are easy to construct and decompose:

```
type Individual = Individual of Double array

// Creating single-case union
let generateIndividual = Individual [|1.0; 2.0|]  

// Decomposing single-case union
let sumIndividual (Individual data) = Array.sum data
```

Comment: I had thought of DUs. But they are comparatively slower, which might be a big turn off for performance critical projects. Anyway, you summed up what was my initial guess.

Comment: allways wonder that people are so concernced with performance - hate to say it but in this cases (where things like the GC and heap vs. stack really matters) it's probably no good idea to really go FP or .net at all...

Comment: devoured elysium: I would also think twice before wrapping a value type such as float or int in a DU, but since arrays are already reference types from start, you probably wouldn't be losing that much.